# How to lock a table before running an insert in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, locking

I have a table "transfers" to track transfer of amount from user A to user B.

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sender   | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| amount   | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| receiver | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Before every new insert to this table, I need to check if the sender has enough balance.

Here is the "users" table

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(100)| NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| balance  | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How do I implement locking here so that users balance doesn't gets reduced by some others methods after passing balance validation.

```
public function store(Transfer $transfer, TransferRequest $request)
{
    $transfer->isAllowed($request); // Will abort if users balance is low

     //what if the users balance gets reduced by some other request here !!

    $transfer->fill($request->all())->save();

    return redirect()->route('transfers.index')->withStatus(__('Transfer successfully created.'));
}
```

Comment: locking a table is excessive. So is locking a row. Can you construct in laravel query that equates to the SQL `UPDATE users SET balance=balance - :amount WHERE balance >= :amount AND id=:userid` and look at the rows affected to see if sufficient balance was there, 0 rows affected means no balance available (or no user id).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sharedLock` or `lockForUpdate` method in laravel documentation 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#pessimistic-locking